# How to call a predefined functions in multiple scenerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am completely new to jquery, here is the code for toggling to collaspe the sidebar.

```
//define script for sidebar toggling
   function togglesidebar() {
         $('#sidebar').toggleClass('column-collapse');


   }

$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);


});
```

It works just fine. But when I add the following code to make it also collapse when screen size is < 768, it stops working.

```
//define script for sidebar toggling
   function togglesidebar() {
         $('#sidebar').toggleClass('column-collapse');


   }

$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);


});
$(window).resize(function(){
windowsize = $(window).width();
if(windowsize < 768) {
      $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);
  });

 });
```

I wonder where the problem is and i will be grateful if someone can help me with it.

EDIT:

Here is the website: 
http://wileyphp.no-ip.biz/tagees/testing.html#

I want to collapse the sidebar when it is windowsize <768px

and

there is a button to toggle collapse/expand in the sidebar. I want it to work at all screen size.

Comment: You have a parse error. These are far easier to spot (though they would be mentioned in your browser's error console) if you indent your code properly.

Comment: not mention the error here, your code would add multiple handlers for  `onclick` event whenever the windowsize becomes smaller than `768`. You should just trigger the click like this `$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click()`

Comment: just wondering, if you define `$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);` wouldn't it just work for all the window sizes? it's another story if you want to trigger it, but the definition works for all window sizes I suppose!

Comment: @AminJafari He might be trying to turn it on in smaller screens and turn it off it larger screens… i'm just guessing :/

Comment: BTW looks like you have a document ready listener inside a ready listener...

Comment: @TilwinJoy then why not just binding it in the smaller version and unbinding it when it's larger?

Comment: @AminJafari i said he might be *trying to*. looks like he doesn't know what to do...

Comment: Dear all,
here is the website:
http://wileyphp.no-ip.biz/tagees/testing.html#

I want to collapse the sidebar when it is windowsize <768px

and

there is a button to toggle collapse/expand in the sidebar. I want it to work at all screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **'}'** at the end of if condition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);
        $(window).resize(function(){
        windowsize = $(window).width();
        if(windowsize < 768) {
              $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(togglesidebar);
        }  /**/ '}' missing here**
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! at least the collasping works.
Still, the sidebar doesn't collapse when I resize the window's width:

here is the website. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: @user3740222, You have initialized variable 'windowsize'?

Comment: here is the website: wileyphp.no-ip.biz/tagees/testing.html# I want to collapse the sidebar when it is windowsize <768px and there is a button to toggle collapse/expand in the sidebar. I want it to work at all screen size.